# Error selenium wire linux with dependency cryptography

Tags: linux, rust, cryptography, seleniumwire

I have a problem installing the seleniumwire library on a Linux server, it sends me an error in the rust for cryptography, I have tried to solve it but I have not been able, any ideas?

```
Caused by:
      process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name syn --edition=2018 /home/ubuntu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.60/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -Cembed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="clone-impls"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="derive"' --cfg 'feature="extra-traits"' --cfg 'feature="full"' --cfg 'feature="parsing"' --cfg 'feature="printing"' --cfg 'feature="proc-macro"' --cfg 'feature="quote"' -C metadata=6cea30fcaa1c5280 -C extra-filename=-6cea30fcaa1c5280 --out-dir /tmp/pip-build-h7zcmi4l/cryptography/src/rust/target/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/pip-build-h7zcmi4l/cryptography/src/rust/target/release/deps --extern proc_macro2=/tmp/pip-build-h7zcmi4l/cryptography/src/rust/target/release/deps/libproc_macro2-5d343acc4305025a.rmeta --extern quote=/tmp/pip-build-h7zcmi4l/cryptography/src/rust/target/release/deps/libquote-f7a0a97a31c8d8ce.rmeta --extern unicode_xid=/tmp/pip-build-h7zcmi4l/cryptography/src/rust/target/release/deps/libunicode_xid-b5e42475a0c5edb5.rmeta --cap-lints allow --cfg syn_disable_nightly_tests` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)

        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
        If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
        successfully install cryptography:
        1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
           users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
        2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
           instructions for your platform.
        3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
           https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
        4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
           https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust
        5) If you are experiencing issues with Rust for *this release only* you may
           set the environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`.
        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================

    error: cargo failed with code: 101


    ----------------------------------------
  Can't rollback cryptography, nothing uninstalled.
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-h7zcmi4l/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-p2wos9g_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-h7zcmi4l/cryptography/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rustc` failed compilation with a `SIGKILL`. This probably happened as a result of it using up too much memory, and the [OOM manager deciding to kill it](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html#htoc102), since the `syn` crate is quite large and requires a lot of RAM to compile. Getting more RAM, or increasing the amount of swap space will allow the compilation to finish.

Comment: Excelent, 
that was the answer, thank you